# Unable to add text to mysql table from Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to add a string in MySQL from a textbox in Java. I have tried many ways from different websites but it is of no use.

I have been trying to add the string to my database and have wasted by whole day in that. My database name is `icseCorner` and my table name is `users`. Please help me with this.

Here is what I have done till now -

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String fname = jTextField1.getText();
    String mname = (jTextField2.getText());
    String lname = (jTextField3.getText());
    String add = (jTextArea1.getText());
    String sch = (jTextField4.getText());
    String usr = (jTextField9.getText());
    String psw = (new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword()));
    String email = (jTextField10.getText());
    String mob = (jTextField11.getText());
    String dist = (jTextField12.getText());
    String state = ((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    String gen = "";

    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected())
      gen = (jRadioButton1.getText());
    else if (jRadioButton2.isSelected())
      gen = (jRadioButton2.getText());

    try {

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
      String sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, middleName, lastName, district, mobile, gender, statae, email, password, username, school, address) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
      PreparedStatement myStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      myStmt.setString(1, fname);
      myStmt.setString(2, mname);
      myStmt.setString(3, lname);
      myStmt.setString(4, add);
      myStmt.setString(5, sch);
      myStmt.setString(6, usr);
      myStmt.setString(7, psw);
      myStmt.setString(8, email);
      myStmt.setString(9, mob);
      myStmt.setString(10, dist);
      myStmt.setString(11, state);
      myStmt.setString(12, gen);
      myStmt.executeUpdate();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered successfull!");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: First thing first,what do you mean by unable to add, its throwing an exception ? if not, then what is the problem.

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) {

    }` Try log the exeception

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` block.

Comment: Please add your connection URL

Comment: Do not swallow exceptions, at minimum log them, or rethrow them. Please log the exception (or use `e.printStackTrace()`) and add the stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **set your prepared statement strings in the same order as you list your table fields** (i.e. firstName, middleName, lastName, district, mobile, gender, statae, email, password, username, school, address).

---

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, middleName, lastName, district, mobile, gender, statae, email, password, username, school, address) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement myStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
myStmt.setString(1, fname);
myStmt.setString(2, mname);
myStmt.setString(3, lname);
myStmt.setString(4, dist);
myStmt.setString(5, mob);
myStmt.setString(6, gen);
myStmt.setString(7, state);
myStmt.setString(8, email);
myStmt.setString(9, psw);
myStmt.setString(10, usr);
myStmt.setString(11, sch);
myStmt.setString(12, add);
```

Comment: @Kaustubh This is a very good point. Try it.